# How can I lowercase an interpolated string inside Perl's qr//?

Tags: perl, expect, tolower, toupper

I'm using Perl Expect module for my SSH connections. I already have a module using sub functions like this:

```
$exp->spawn("ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$connectTimeout $user\@$ip") or die ("unable to spawn \n");
@obj=$exp->expect( $commandTimeout,
[ qr/.*$quotedhostname.*/ => sub
        {
        print "connected \n";
        $exp->send("term length 0", "\n");
        $exp->expect($commandTimeout2,);
        &executeCommands();
        }
],
```

But my $quotedhostname is UPPERCASE. I need to catch this when it is LOWERCASE too.
Isn't there a way to do something like this:

```
[ qr/.*$quotedhostname.*/ OR /.*$lowercasequotedhostname.*/ => sub
```

Or should I just have to add another `[qr]` block ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `/i` flag to make the match case-insensitive:

```
[ qr/$quotedhostname/i => sub
```

You also don't need the `.*` at the start and end, it'll match anyway (they only serve to make it slower here).